# Null value handling

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Let's assume i have a query

```
SELECT val FROM tbl
```

I want to write query that will output "ValueIsNotNull" when val is not null and "ValueIsNull" when val is null. Is it possible to do this with one line. As of now i found only `ISNULL(val,'ValueIsNull') AS val1`. But if value is not null then original value is printed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select
    case
        when val is null then 'ValueIsNull'
        else 'ValueIsNotNull'
    end
    as NewVal
from tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. And one offtopic question. Is there any way in C# to write multiple line strings?

Comment: Yes, use the `@` in front of the string for multiline strings.  That's a very random question.

Answer (score 3):

You want the case statement function:

```
select (case when val is NULL then 'ValueIsNull' else 'ValueIsNotNull' end)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 'ValueIsNotNull' ELSE 'ValueIsNull' END
```